# Cast struct to its first member inside a function(void *)

Tags: c, struct, implicit-conversion, void-pointers

I have an opaque structure like this:

```
// base.h
typedef struct Base Base;
Base *create_base(void);
void base_set_first(Base *, int);

// base.c
#include "base.h"

struct Base {
    int first;
};

Base *create_base(void)
{
    Base *new = malloc(sizeof(Base));
    return new;
}

void base_set_first(Base *base, int value)
{
    base->first = value;
}
```

The first member of another opaque structure is a pointer to *Base*:

```
// derived.h
typedef struct Derived Derived;
Derived *create_derived(void);

// derived.c
#include "derived.h"
#include "base.h"

struct Derived {
    Base *base;
};

Derived *create_derived(void)
{
    Derived *new = malloc(sizeof(Derived));
    new->base = create_base();
    return new;
}
```

**Is it 'legal' to pass a structure *Derived* to a function that accepts a void * and then cast it to its first member?**

```
void function(void *ptr)
{
    Base *base = (Base *)ptr; // <-- it seems to work well but is this 'legal' or UB?
    base_set_first(base, 1);
    //...
}

Derived *d = create_derived();
function(d);
```

Comment: Yes, it's valid. There's no padding at the beginning of a structure.

Comment: @Fe2O3 That's not the same thing, since you would presumably cast them to the full type of the array elements, not the type of a member.

Comment: Your code is not doing what your words say. The first member of derived is a Base *, not a Base. You may be able to do what you said, but not what you coded.

Comment: Deleted my comments based on @AviBerger and those sharp eyes... :-)

Comment: Sidenote: Having object creation require multiple dynamic memory allocations is not really efficient. It would be better if `base` was a regular member variable rather than pointer.

Comment: Sidenote 2: I have done OOP with inheritance in C in the past, I don't really recommend it. Trying to mimick anything more complicated than basic objects and methods in C will lead to inefficient and overly complicated spaghetti code. Unless you do this for learning purposes only, it is better to use language that is actually designed to support these features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's valid to cast a structure pointer to a pointer to the type of its first member. The [specification](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p15) says:

> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. **A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member** (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

But that's not what you're doing. Your code in `function()` would be correct if the declaration were:

```
struct Derived {
    Base base;
};
```

But in your actual code, `Derived.base` is a `Base*` pointer, not a `Base`, so you need to add a level of indirection.

```
void function(void *ptr)
{
    Base **base = (Base **)ptr;
    base_set_first(*base, 1);
    //...
}
```

Comment: You're right, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I assume that it should be `base_set_first(*base, 1)`.

Comment: Yeah, it's easy to get lost in the maze of indirections when you're not actually debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

From the C Standard (6.3.2.3 Pointers)

> 1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any
> object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a
> pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the
> original pointer.

and (6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers)

> 15 Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units
> in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order
> in which they are declared. **A pointer to a structure object,
> suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is
> a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.**
> There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its
> beginning.