# Declaring a forward declaration to another type

Tags: c

I have following case:

.h file:

```
struct my_public_type;
struct my_public_type *my_public_type_alloc();
```

and inside the .c file, I want to use a 3rd lib type as declaration of `my_public_type`, which of course has a different name. Not sure if I explained this clearly, I want to have such a function in .c file:

```
struct my_public_type *my_public_type_alloc()
{
    struct third_party_type *ret = third_party_alloc();
    return ret; //compiler will complain here
}
```

And avoid having a wrapper like this:

```
struct my_public_type {
    struct third_party_type *inner;
};
```

Is this somehow possible with `typedef` or another trick? After all, this is only a pointer.

Comment: If you want to totally wrap a third-party API without disclosing it to the users of your own wrapper API (completely hiding it), then using an opaque wrapper-structure like you show is really the only way.

Comment: Why not just have your header forward declare `struct third_party_type` and skip `my_public_type` entirely? Are you planning to indefinitely hide the discrepancy from the user if the third party type changes, by continuing to present your own opaque type that no longer matches the layout of the third party type by rewriting all your code to convert between one and the other at interface points?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Did you mean return a `struct third_party_type *`?  It's not possible to return a `struct` by value and keep its contents private.

Comment: @ShadowRanger In that case, which function should the user call to free the object, 3rd party, or the one I will define? Why would I care about the layout as the user is using a pointer? 
I'm experimenting and learning C, imagine a scenario where there are 2 different implementations of the same header, each having a different third_party_type, what then?

Comment: This is a kludge, but it is defined by the C standard: If `third_party_type` appears in the third-party header only as `struct third_party type`, you can `#define third_party_type my_public_type` before you include the header, so that `struct my_public_type` and `struct third_party_type` are the same when compiling your source file. The third-party source file will still be compiled with its own name for the structure, but this works because all pointers to structure types have the same representation and alignment requirements (C 2018 6.2.5 28),…

Comment: … and this implies interchangeability as arguments to functions and return values from functions (note 49). Nonetheless, as this is a kludge, I would suggest simply casting as the current answer says.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I said nothing about returning anything. I was talking about using their name instead of your own, with corresponding pointers (effectively a text search and replace of `my_public_type` with `third_party_type` with some small cleanup where that would cause unnecessary duplication; pointers would still be pointers). I'm well aware that you can't return by value with just a forward declaration, not sure where you're seeing I was suggesting anything like that.

Comment: @konradk: Why *not* just have them use the third party libraries allocation and freeing functions and avoid defining your own entirely? If there is something you're doing that is special and different from the third-party library, okay, sure, but that risks incompatibility with the third-party library to start, and you haven't presented any evidence that you have a need to do this.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: One may wish to extend a third-party library by providing a routine it does not (but that operates on its data) or a modified version of one of its routines (e.g., perform some step, call library routine, perform some step) or provide options to use different third-party libraries through one API you define. For any of these, it is cleaner to provide a complete API of your own and not have your client call any of the third-party library routines. You would make your own free routine that merely calls the library’s free routine.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: There's potential reasons to do it. But given all the hard-coding, I'm not seeing what the OP thinks they're gaining from this (it's not like the API consumers won't need the third party library for this to work, they just get to avoid including its headers directly), and suspect an XY problem.

Comment: Obviously the compiler will complain if the structs are not compatible. Then you simply can't use them in place of each other. For two structs to be compatible, they need identical members, same tag name etc. Otherwise no trivial conversion between them is possible. Please clarify what this third party thing is supposed to be. Just a "dumb" function like `malloc` returning a raw pointer to a chunk with no type? Or a different struct declared elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just cast the pointer.

```
struct my_public_type* my_public_type_alloc()
{
  struct third_party_type * ret = third_party_alloc();
  return (struct my_public_type*)ret;
}
```

Of course, you'll have to make sure to cast things back and forth whenever you need to.

The real question is -- why? If you want to hide the "third_party_type", you could just forward declare that and use it, saving the need to cast things.

Comment: I'm not sure why this received a downvote - see [**Cast struct to its first member inside a function(void *)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73723425/cast-struct-to-its-first-member-inside-a-functionvoid), among a few.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: This answer does not involve converting between a pointer to a structure and a pointer to its first member, just converting between pointers to two different structure types.

Comment: I have no idea what makes you think that pointers to these two structs are compatible..?

Comment: @Lundin: Nothing in this answer says the two structures are compatible or relies on the two structures being compatible. The client of OP’s API is not intended to use either structure. The client will merely receive a pointer to a structure type from OP’s API and will pass that pointer back to routines in OP’s API and will not have any definition for the structure. There need not be a definition of the structure anywhere in the program.

Comment: @EricPostpischil There is not nearly enough information provided to jump to such conclusions. In particular we don't know if a structure definition is present or not, ie if this is meant to also do something else except being a "dumb" name wrapping class.

Comment: @Lundin: As I wrote, nothing in this answer says the two structures are compatible or relies on the two structures being compatible. Presuming that this holds for the rest of OP’s code would be an assumption, but it is one that entirely fits the circumstances. But, putting that aside, it remains true that nothing in this answer says the two structures are compatible or relies on the two structures being compatible…

Comment: … This answer shows conversion of `struct third_party_type *` to `struct my_public_type *` and says OP will have to convert back, and these conversions are fully defined by the C standard. They do not require the structure types to be compatible.

Answer (score 1):

It's early and I've only had two cups of coffee so far, but my approach would be something like this:

Header:

```
/**
 * my_public_type.h
 */
#ifndef MY_PUBLIC_TYPE_H
#define MY_PUBLIC_TYPE_H

typedef void my_public_type;

my_public_type *my_public_type_alloc( /* args */ );
void do_thing( my_public_type *handle /*, args */ );
void do_another_thing( my_public_type *handle /*, args */ );
void my_public_type_free( my_public_type *p );

#endif
```

Implementation:

```
/**
 * my_public_type.c
 */
#include "my_public_type.h"
#include "third_party_lib.h"

my_public_type *my_public_type_alloc( /* args */ )
{
  return third_party_alloc( /* args */ );
}

void do_thing( my_public_type *handle /*, args */ )
{
  struct third_party_type *p = handle;
  p->some_member = some_arg;
  p->some_other_member = some_other_arg;
  third_party_library_call( p /*, other args */ );
  ...
}

void do_other_thing( my_public_type *handle /*, args * / )
{
  struct third_party_type *p = handle;
  p->yet_another_member = some_different_arg;
  another_third_party_library_call( p /*, yet more args */);
  ...
}
```

giving us something like

```
my_public_type *handle = my_public_type_alloc();
if ( handle )
{
  do_thing( handle, foo, bar, bletch );
  do_another_thing( handle, blah, blurga );
  ...
}
my_public_type_free( handle );
```

No details of the third-party type are exposed in the `my_public_type.h` header, and `my_public_type` itself is just a `void`, so you can't create objects of that type; you can only create pointers to it.  This allows you to easily swap out different implementations if you choose to use a different third-party library.

You don't want to do a one-to-one mapping of your functions to the third-party library's -- might as well just expose it directly in that case.  You want to analyze what functions you need to provide *for your project*, then map those actions onto the library.

Comment: Early in the morning and already 2 cups of coffee, you mad? Didn't know you could define the type as void, seems reasonable